# Can not reference a type through an expression why?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create 2 forms.

In Form 1 I want to save all new contacts, so I can display them later, and I am adding second button opening Form 2 where I want to create a Contact and after closing the window to save the contact in to the list that is created in Form 1. I am getting error:

```
Can not reference a type through an expression
```

on `f2.Contacts = this.contacts;` and I don't know why.

Form 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Contacts contacts = new Contacts();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public  class Contacts
        {
          private  List<Contacts> people = new List<Contacts>();

          public List<Contacts> People
          {
              get { return people; }
          }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Contacts = this.contacts;
            f2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public class Contacts
        {
            private List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

            public List<Person> Persons
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.persons;
                }
            }
        }

        public  Contacts contacts { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            p.LastName = textBox2.Text;
            p.PhoneNumber = textBox3.Text;
            p.eMail = textBox4.Text;
            this.contacts.Persons.Add(p);
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

            public string eMail { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on dude. `Contacts` is the class name, `contacts` is what you want to assign to. Not sure why you have `Contacts` implemented twice, but that's another issue.

Comment: Plain syntax error. `Contacts` in `f2.Contacts` is a type, not a property.

Comment: f2,`Contacts` is a class, you property is called `contacts`

Comment: The roots of your problems: lots of things with the same name and not respecting naming conventions. These conventions are here to help you, ignore them at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

You are (accidentally) referring to the nested `Contacts` class. When you use

```
f2.Contacts = this.contacts;
```

you refer to the **class** `Form2.Contacts`.

But you want to refer to the `Form2.contacts` **property**:

```
f2.contacts = this.contacts;
```